# Can I store a Parquet file with a dictionary column having mixed types in their values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, parquet, pyarrow

I am trying to store a Python Pandas DataFrame as a Parquet file, but I am experiencing some issues. One of the columns of my Pandas DF contains dictionaries as such:

```py
import pandas as pandas

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ColA": [1, 2, 3],
    "ColB": ["X", "Y", "Z"],
    "ColC": [
        { "Field": "Value" },
        { "Field": "Value2" },
        { "Field": "Value3" }
    ]
})

df.to_parquet("test.parquet")
```

Now, that works perfectly fine, the problem is when one of the nested values of the dictionary has a different type than the rest. For instance:

```py
import pandas as pandas

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ColA": [1, 2, 3],
    "ColB": ["X", "Y", "Z"],
    "ColC": [
        { "Field": "Value" },
        { "Field": "Value2" },
        { "Field": ["Value3"] }
    ]
})

df.to_parquet("test.parquet")
```

This throws the following error:

`ArrowInvalid: ('cannot mix list and non-list, non-null values', 'Conversion failed for column ColC with type object')`

Notice how, for the last row of the DF, the `Field` property of the `ColC` dictionary is a list instead of a string.

Is there any workaround to be able to store this DF as a Parquet file?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`ColC` is a UDT (user defined type) with one field called `Field` of type `Union of String, List of String`.

In theory arrow supports it, but in practice it has a hard time figuring out what the type of `ColC` is. Even if you were providing the schema of your data frame explicitly, it wouldn't work because this type of conversion (converting unions from pandas to arrow/parquet) isn't supported yet.

```
union_type = pa.union(
    [pa.field("0",pa.string()), pa.field("1", pa.list_(pa.string()))],
    'dense'
)
col_c_type = pa.struct(
    [
        pa.field('Field', union_type)
    ]
)

schema=pa.schema(
    [
        pa.field('ColA', pa.int32()),
        pa.field('ColB', pa.string()),
        pa.field('ColC', col_c_type),
    ]
)

df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ColA": [1, 2, 3],
    "ColB": ["X", "Y", "Z"],
    "ColC": [
        { "Field": "Value" },
        { "Field": "Value2" },
        { "Field": ["Value3"] }
    ]
})

pa.Table.from_pandas(df, schema)
```

This gives you this error:

`('Sequence converter for type union[dense]<0: string=0, 1: list<item: string>=1> not implemented', 'Conversion failed for column ColC with type object'`

Even if you create the arrow table manually it won't be able to convert it to parquet (again, union are not supported).

```
import io
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

col_a = pa.array([1, 2, 3], pa.int32())
col_b = pa.array(["X", "Y", "Z"], pa.string())

xs = pa.array(["Value", "Value2", None], type=pa.string())
ys = pa.array([None, None, ["value3"]], type=pa.list_(pa.string()))
types = pa.array([0, 0, 1], type=pa.int8())

col_c = pa.UnionArray.from_sparse(types, [xs, ys])

table = pa.Table.from_arrays(
    [col_a, col_b, col_c],
    schema=pa.schema([
        pa.field('ColA', col_a.type),
        pa.field('ColB', col_b.type),
        pa.field('ColC', col_c.type),
    ])
)

with io.BytesIO() as buffer:
    pq.write_table(table, buffer)
```

```
Unhandled type for Arrow to Parquet schema conversion: sparse_union<0: string=0, 1: list<item: string>=1>
```

I think your only option for now it to use a struct where fields have got different names for string value and list of string values.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "ColA": [1, 2, 3],
    "ColB": ["X", "Y", "Z"],
    "ColC": [
        { "Field1": "Value" },
        { "Field1": "Value2" },
        { "Field2": ["Value3"] }
    ]
})

df.to_parquet('/tmp/hello')
```

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem and fixed by converting `ColC` to string:

```
df['ColC'] = df['ColC'].astype(str)
```

I am not sure this would not create a problem in the future, don't quote me.